# Escaping HTML attributes

Tags: html, escaping, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to render an escaped string into an a html attribute (using Twitter Bootstrap to render a popover of the escaped code used to generate what the user is looking at):

Something like:

```
<a class="btn" href="#" data-content='<pre>$escaped_code</pre>' rel="popover" data-orginal-title="$title">some cool looking thing</a>
```

The problem is that the browser will parse and unescape the escape code potentially allowing for unpleasantness.

Comment: have you got an example of the escape_code causing issues?

Comment: Show us the markup that the browser sees — what's in `$escaped_code`?

Comment: edit:  Doh- figured it out, the answer is to of course manually escape it twice.  To noob to answer my own question so feel free to get some e-points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to of course manually escape it twice.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `<` or `>` in HTML attributes, for one:

```
<a class="btn" href="#" data-content='&lt;pre&gt;$escaped_code&lt;/pre&gt;' rel="popover" data-orginal-title="$title">some cool looking thing</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what sort of escaped string you have there. I am assuming PHP. However, the escape characters are different for HTML:

http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php

The fact that you are trying to put HTML tags into an HTML attribute suggests that you aren't using the correct HTML escape characters. Make sure everything within the HTML tag is escaped for HTML.